# Differencing multiple time series with different difference order

Tags: r

I have a time series object that consists of *n* time series and with *ndiffs* I obtain a vector which differencing order is necessary to get stationary time series. Now I want to do exactly that. But

```
tmp <- sapply(ts, ndiffs, alpha=0.05, test=c("kpss", "adf", "pp")) 
sapply(ts, function(x) diff(x,differences = tmp) )
```

..is not working.

Are there some ideas without using a *for* loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map2` from the `purrr` package to loop over both vectors:

```
purrr::map2(.x = ts,
            .y = tmp,
            .f = function(x, y){
              diff(x, differences = y)
            })
```

or with `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(x, y){
  diff(x, difference = y)
}, x = ts, y = tmp)
```

The problem with sapply is it only iterates over a single object.